# Is it possible to develop a baseCSP card minidriver over PKCS#11?

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11, cryptoapi, cng

in the past we developed a pkcs#11 module to be used for web authentication and digital signature. Now we are asked to develop a card minidriver for windows to achieve the same functionalities. It it possible to implement the cardmod.h interface on the top of PKCS#11?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is such a project on github...

https://github.com/CardContact/sc-hsm-embedded/wiki/minidriver

Comment: Hi, thank you for you comment. This project is not exacty what i was planning to do. Infact "The CSP-Minidriver is build on top of the token interface, which is part of the PKCS#11 module. It inherits card and crypto support from the PKCS#11 module." I mean a CSP minidriver built on top of the PKCS#11 interface.

Comment: I think i should vote your answer because this is a good starting project.